# Java : Set result set from JPA Paginated Query to custom class

Tags: java, jpa, arraylist, resultset

Here is the scenario.

I am trying to get a list of records in my resource layer. It has the following code;

```
PagedResponse<Person> pagedResponse= new PagedResponse<Person>();
```

There is a call to Business implementation as

```
pagedResponse = facadeLocator.getPersonFacade().findAllRecords(getUserId(), fromrow, maxrows);
```

Now in the Business implementation, I use named query as;

```
Query query = getNamedQuery("Person.findAll");
```

I have the response as

```
pagedResponse = executePagedQuery(query, firstResults, maxResults);
```

and inside executePagedQuery(), I have;

```
List resultList = query.getResultList();
```

The response returned pagedResponse is of custom type PagedResponse class with 2 members;

```
private Long totalRecords;
    private List<T> records;
```

Now in my Person class, I have

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Person.findAll", query = "Select DISTINCT(p.personName), p.personAge, p.personGender from Person p where p.personAge = :personAge")
```

Now here is what happens at runtime.

I get the "records" as **Vector** with members as

```
[0] = Object[]
[1] = Object[]
```

Coming back to the resource layer, I want to iterate through the response and set it in a list

```
List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<Person>();
```

So what are the options I have.

I have tried doing

```
    for(Object[] person: pagedResponse.getRecords()) {
                Person p = new Person();
                p.setPersonName((String)person[0]);
// Setting other values
    personList.add(p);
    }
```

But it says incompatible types for the line

```
for(Object[] person: pagedResponse.getRecords()) {
```

Just to add, I did not face any incompatible type issue when my query did not return select columns and instead returned all the columns like;

```
query = "SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE
```

So I have 2 questions;

```
1. Why was there no type casting issues when I was returning all the columns using the named query (It showed the type as "Person" and not generic type as showing after using the named query with specific columns)
2. Using the query with specific columns, what is the right approach to set the values returned from the query in the resource layer ?
```

Answer (score 1):

The query with many individual `SELECT`ed values is supposed to return a list of lists. Maybe you want to define a bean with an appropriate constructor:

```
package com.foo;

public class PersonData {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private Sex gender;

    public PersonData(String name, int age, Sex gender) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age= age;
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    // getters/setters
}
```

And run the query as:

```
SELECT NEW com.foo.PersonData(DISTINCT(p.personName), p.personAge, p.personGender)
FROM Person p WHERE p.personAge = :personAge
```

Now `getResultList()` should return a list of `PersonData` objects. Though I haven't used the nested `new PersonData(DISTINCT(...))` syntax...